# Surround with method/function call in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to surround selection with an arbitrary method call?

Ex: let say, you have `return dx;` and you want to quickly transform it into `return Math.abs(dx);`

I'm aware of templates but then you have to hard code your surrounding(`Math.abs` in this case) and I'm looking for a generic solution, not bounded to any predefined method.

**UPD 22.01.2019:**
As @de-li pointed out, the `.arg` postfix template is added. At the moment confirmed for Java. Feel free to vote for the Kotlin support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29398

**UPD:**
`.arg` template is available for Kotlin since `1.3.40-dev-568`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Move to the end of the code and type '.arg', then press enter, IDE will add a pair of brackets to wrap the value and move the cursor to the beginning, then you can the method name you want.

Comment: works for java, not yet for kotlin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29398

Comment: UPD: `.arg` template is available for Kotlin since `1.3.40-dev-568`.

Answer (score 82):

You could create a live template looking something like this:

```
$END$($SELECTION$)
```

and then just select the text you want to wrap, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to show the suround with popup and select your template as illustrated in the image below:

[image]

That way you have generic template and you don't have to hardcode method name into it.

Comment: Neat! Similar to existing ```(expr)``` but you nailed it with ```$END$``` in front. Now, the real question is how did you make this beautiful gif? :)

Comment: @Ghedeon [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/). Really nice app. Just gotta find something like this for Mac :)

Comment: that would be nice if we could use the `.par` post fix feature and move the cursor to the left

Comment: Is there a way to create the selection (the thing you want to surround) using the same kind of pop-up that happens when you extract a variable (Ctrl+Alt+V) or extract a method (Ctrl+Alt+M) etc? It's making that initial selection by hand that's killing me.

Comment: @arekolek's answer to use ⌥+⌘+J for Surround With Live Template requires less key presses (no pressing up twice for me at least since it's the only live template I have).

Answer (score 17):

To add to the answer above:

1. Go to `Android Studio > Preferences`.
2. Choose `Editor > Live Templates` in the navigation.
3. Expand the `surround` group of live templates.
4. Select `P (Surround with())` and click `Duplicate` on the right.
5. Put `F` as Abbreviation, `Surround with function call` as Description and `$END$($SELECTION$)` as Template text.
6. Click to `Change` the Applicable scope and select `Expression`, `String`, and `Other` under `Java`.

Now it's possible to just select something, hit <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Surround with Live Template) and the new live template is first on this list, so just hit enter.

Comment: Thank you, but Jesus Christ JetBrains, why isn't that build-in?!